# WPF - Cambiar el color de un boton cuando el mouse esta encima

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wpf

Buenas, como puedo aplicar un estilo a un botón cuando el mouse pase por encima:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria mi código para aplicar el estilo a mi boton:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TabButtonFirst">
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"  BorderBrush="#D3F2EE" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" Background="#FF57CDBD" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3A887E"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Mi boton:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Style="{StaticResource TabButtonFirst}" Content="INGRESAR" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="#FFAEF1E8" BorderBrush="#FFF7F7F7"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has vuelto a establecer el `background` en la definición del botón, por lo que estás invalidando el que has definido dentro del estilo.
Elimina la propiedad `background` de la definición del botón (`button1`) y funcionará.
Por otra parte veo que has definido el estilo en la misma ventana, lee sobre la creación de diccionarios donde podrás aglutinar los distintos estilos usados en la aplicación. Te ofrecerán mayor control y será más fácil de gestionar en el caso de que algún día quieras dotar a tu aplicación de distintos `skins`.